# Vanderbild ACTProx ISO-B 125 Khz Access card serial number conversion

Tags: data-conversion, rfid, serial-number, common-access-card

I have been trying to help a colleague find info on ACTProx cards to see if I can confirm if the 10 digit serial number on the back of the card in some way corresponds to the data stored on the card or is a completely different series of numbers. I have yet to succeed.

From what I understood in my research, each one of these RFID cards contains an EPC value in their data blocks that gets translated by a reader in order to determine if the card is valid or not, and some access card manufacturers have it in a way that the serial number on the back corresponds to the value in the data block that gets checked by the access card readers.

I couldn't find any specific resources that would dissuade me from thinking this isn't at all possible, but I would apreciate if you let me know if I have grossly misunderstood how these cards work.

Edit: Card manufacturer ended up responding to me through contact email. Yes the digits correspond to what the card readers actually use to check. They just didn't explain how to conversion to binary actually works (It was a long shot anyways)

So now all that is left is finding out what is the protocol used in order to convert the value stored in memory to the binary that the reader outputs, to which I still am finding no info on. Would apreciate if anybody who knows could tell me.